# Postgres SQL: Best way to check for new data in a database I don't control

Tags: sql, polling, notify, listen

For an application I am writing, I need to be able to identify when new data is inserted into several tables of a database.

The problem is two fold, this data will be been inserted many times per minute into sometimes very large databases (and I need to be sensitive to demand / database polling issues) and I have no control of the application creating this data (so as far as I know, I can't use the notify / listen functionality available within postgres for exactly this kind of task*).

Any suggestion regarding a good strategy would be much appreciated.

*I believe the application controlling this data is using the notify / listen functionality itself, but I haven't a clue how (if at all possible) to know what the "channel" it uses externally and if it is ever able to latch on to that.

Comment: Do these tables have any useful fields such as datetime created or datetime updated?

Comment: datetime created...yes (but entries aren't ever updated, so no to the second).

Comment: Any thoughts on how to use those datetime created columns?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you need something in the table that you can use to determine newness, and there are a few approaches.

A timestamp column would let you use the date but you'd still have the application issue of storing a date outside of your database, and data that isn't in the database means another realm of data to manage. Yuck.

A tracking table that stored last update/insert timestamps on a per-table basis could give you what you want. You'd want to use a trigger to maintain the last-DML timestamp.

A solution you don't want to use is a serial (integer) id that comes from nextval, for any purpose than uniqueness. The standard/common mistake is to presume serial keys will be contiguous (they're not) or monotonic (they're not).